# Expression Engine Create a row for each entry Php or EE?

Tags: php, foreach, expressionengine, cartthrob

I am trying to create a txt file for a client shop with entries in the following way:

Channel TAG:

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="1937" variable_prefix="items_"}

{items_title} {items_quantity} {items_price_numeric}

{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

Other PHP needed variables: `$order_id = XXXX` -> This one must be the first one on every book row.

I want that for each entry ( book in the channel ) a ROW to be created one above the other with the `$order_id` in front of each one like this :

```
XXXX Book Title 1 50

XXXX boook2 tiitle 2 100
```

How to do that in PHP so that to be FOR EACH entry to get a new line?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a PHP loop in your EE template, PHP will create one row for each order.  You'll use this row to write out the ee code you need which will generate its own EE rows describing what is in the order.  You can pass the PHP variable forward to EE using the assign_variable ee tag.  Am following you correctly?

Comment: Hei ALLInOne, I need php to create a a row for each Book that is outputed by the channel tags, I don't know php :( Can you be more explicit in your detail ?

Comment: Not sure I can help you unless you post more code or explain a little more.  Are you saying that $order_id is a value that is only in PHP and not represented in expression engine?  How are you getting $order_id? Don't make us guess, show us what you've tried please.